# VS Server - can't connect to tunnel anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hey I'm working on vscode on my mac running a tunnel on a laptop, until now it was working great but i can't succeed to connect to the remote tunnel anymore
The tunnel is on in vscode on the laptop ,when i try to connect using the remote extension on my mac i can see its online and when i try to connect i can see multiple notification of connection [image]

Then i get this error (VsCode is up to date on both devices)

[image]

When i try to connect to the remote throughout website browser i get this error

[image]

And that's what going on in the tunnel output

[image]

If someone know how to help

Comment: Looks like a release got fumbled and a fix is coming "soon" hopefully: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8582